# PHP undefined index when uploading images

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload images via a form, but when it comes to pressing the upload image button I get an error saying "cannot upload files of this type" which is `$msg6`in the `admin.php` file, and also it echos out `undefined index from line 40-45`.

The `admin.phtml` is:

```
<body id="propertyForm" class="bg-light-gray">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container p-3 ">
        <div class="row pt-5 ">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 mx-auto pt-5 shadow bg-light">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 mx-auto pb-5">
                        <a href="" class="center-block btn btn-xl">Please use the form below to add your property to Mile Market</a>
                        <div align="center">
                            <form id="addProperty" method="POST">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Property Title">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="Type (House/Flat)">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Price">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="sqft" placeholder="Square Footage">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="beds" placeholder="Beds">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="baths" placeholder="Baths">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="agentPhone" placeholder="Agent Phone Number">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="agentEmail" placeholder="Agent Email">
                                </div>



                                <form action="admin.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <input type="file" name="file" onsubmit="">
                                    <button type="submit" name="uploadImageButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Upload Image</button>
                                </form>

                                <button type="submit" name="addPropertyButton" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Property</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The `admin.php` file is:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("admin.phtml");
require_once("assets/database.php");
$conn = new connectDB();
$myDatabase = $conn->getConnectDB();

// checks if add property button has been pressed
if(isset($_POST['addPropertyButton'])){
$sqlQUERY = "SELECT name FROM properties"; // selects all properties names 
from campsite table
$data = $myDatabase->query($sqlQUERY)->fetchAll();

// loop to check each name iteratively, sets $found true if loop finds the 
same name so insert code isn't run
$found = false;
foreach($data as $row){
    if($_POST['name'] == $row['name']){
        $found = true;
        $msg1 = "Property: " . $_POST['name'] . " already exists on Mile Market!.";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg1');  </script>"; // Echo error message
        break;
    }
}

// if name doesn't exist in the database then insert it
if(!$found){
    //query to insert database
    $sqlQUERY = "insert into properties (name, address, type, price, sqft, beds, baths, agentPhone, agentEmail) values ('" . $_POST['name'] . "','" . $_POST['address'] . "','" . $_POST['type'] . "','" . $_POST['price'] . "','" . $_POST['sqft'] . "','" . $_POST['beds'] . "','" . $_POST['baths'] . "','" . $_POST['agentPhone'] . "','" . $_POST['agentEmail'] . "')";
    echo $sqlQUERY;
    $myDatabase->prepare($sqlQUERY)->execute();
    $msg2 = "Success! Property: ".$_POST['name']." has been added";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg2');  </script>";

    $sqlFindID = "select id from properties";

    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName); // gets file extension
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt)); // gets file extension and changes to lowercase

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'); // allows types of jpegs and pngs

    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if($fileError === 0){ // if no errors
            if($fileSize < 10000000){ // if file size less than 10mb
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt; // makes a unique file name so each file is different, adds file extension after
                $fileDestination = 'assets/images/imgProperty'.$fileNameNew; // uploads file to portfolio subfolder for admin to see
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination); // gets temp file location and where we want to upload to
                $sqlQUERY = "INSERT INTO images(image) VALUES ('". $fileNameNew."')";
                echo $sqlQUERY;
                $myDatabase->prepare($sqlQUERY)->execute();
            } else {
                $msg4 = "Your file is too big";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg4');  </script>";
            }
        } else {
            $msg5 = "There was an error uploading your file";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg5');  </script>";
        }
    } else {
        $msg6 = "Cannot upload files of this type";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg6');  </script>";
    }

} else {
    $msg3 = "Failed to add property, please check all fields are correct";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg3');  </script>";
}
}
```

Please can someone let me know why this error occurs, as far as I'm concerned it should work as I've used this code in a previous project before with no issues!

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have `onsubmit=""` in the file input? It won't cause a problem, but it's meaningless there.

Comment: @Barmar it was there when I had some JavaScript attached to it, but for testing purposes I took it out

Comment: You have invalid HTML. You can't nest forms inside each other.

Comment: I don't know for sure if that's the reason for your error, but you need to fix it. See if that resolves the error.

Comment: Putting something in the `onsubmit` will never work. The submit event only gets sent to forms, not individual input fields.

Comment: @Barmar Moving the form to upload images outside of the form worked, however when I press upload property how will it have an image attached to it as the data disappears once the button has been pressed. Furthermore, when I press upload image it now says `Warning: move_uploaded_file(/images/imgProperty/608b4619956e95.46467614.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` and points to line 57 in the `admin.php` file which is `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);`

Comment: That error message doesn't match your code. Where is the `/` after `imgProperty` coming from?

Comment: If you want to upload the image when submitting the property, you shouldn't have two forms. Just put the file input in the main form, and put the upload processing into the controller for that form.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I pasted in the wrong msg, I tried adding in a `/` on the `$fileDestination` line to see if that would fix it

Comment: The error means that the `/images` directory doesn't exist. Are you sure it's in the root of your filesystem? Maybe it should be under the webserver root directory?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not quite sure how to do what you said in regards to the two forms, please could you provide me with an example? Also thank you for your help thus far, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Just move the code that processes `$_FILES['file']` into the script that adds the new property.

Comment: Since you didn't post that code, I don't know how to write an example for it. The code would be identical to what you already have, except for the `isset($_POST['uploadImageButton'])` check.

Comment: BTW, how does your `INSERT` link the image to the property?

Comment: @Barmar I plan on linking the image to the property by adding to the `INSERT` query by joining my `properties` table `agentEmail` attribute to the `images` tables' `email` attribute. However, I don't think this is the correct way to do it, do you have any suggestions on how I could link them?

Comment: The `images` table should have a foreign key to the primary key of the `properties` table. If you put them in the same form, then after you insert into `properties`, you can get the auto-increment ID of the propery, and put that in the `images` insert.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited the tables so that `images` table has a foreign key to `properties` tables' ID but I'm unsure how to do the query after I've inserted the property into the `properties` table. I have edited the body of my question to include the full code for `admin.php`.

Comment: Please ignore in `admin.php` the line that says `$sqlFindID`

Comment: If you're using mysqli, you use `$stmt->insert_id` to get the ID that was assigned, if you're using PDO it's `$stmt->lastInsertID`

Comment: The full code of admin.php is not relevant. The `addProperty` form doesn't have `action="admin.php"`. Since it has no action, it defaults to its own URL.

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much for your comments, I managed to fix it and now the images link to the property correctly and insert into my database!